# How to dynamically determine how many threads a multipart upload should have based on a machine specifications?

Tags: multithreading, browser, upload, multipart

I am using multipart upload to upload large files to s3. When using multipart how can I determine using code how many threads I should put per upload?

How do I determine how many threads an upload should handle. What qualities should I look for, using code, to determine how many threads someone's computer and browser can handle?